# Error en Select - laravel 8

Tags: laravel, livewire

estoy siguiendo ejemplo de tutorial y en ese ejemplo si puedo crear registros pero al momento de querer editar un registro me muesra el siguiente error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from "posts" where "id" = 23 limit 1)
http://localhost:8000/livewire/message/post-component

el error se produce aquí

```
public function edit(Post $post) --- aquí
    {
        $this->name = $post->name;
        $this->body = $post->body;
    }
```

el evento que se dispara es este:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
                <tr class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">{{$post->id}}</td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">{{$post->name}}</td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">{{$post->body}}</td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                        <button wire:click='edit({{$post}})' class="btn">Editar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
@endforeach
```

repito si puedo crear un registro pero al intenter recuperar para editar no puedo y mi inexperiencia no puede dejar ver donde esta el problema

Comment: Asumo que el método edit está en el componente cierto?

Comment: si claro, como te digo que si puedo crear un registro nuevo, ademas en el ejemplo que estoy siguiente si funciona, pero a mi no y no se donde puede estar el problema. esos componentes han sido generados con php artisan make:livewire Post